# Rewriting URL using htaccess and mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I am new to htaccess mod_rewrite rules. I want to eliminate the GET variables from the URL. I have tried the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?[^\ ]+
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L] #remove query string
```

The above rule eliminated the query `?id`, but it redirected the URL as `www.example.com/admin/test.php` without the subdirectory `project` and with the extension `.php`

I want to convert

```
www.example.com/project/admin/test.php?id=1
```

to

```
www.example.com/project/admin/test
```

Comment: If id is **2**, rewrite needs be happen or not?

Comment: The id is dynamic.. if any id is passed it should rewrite  @undone

Comment: So, you just want to remove **.php** from the end if URL?

Comment: Want to remove the .php and also want to prevent the removal of subdirectory "project" from the existing URL. Because the above code removes "project" subdirectory too. i want like www.example.com/project/admin/test

Answer (score 0):

Browsing **www.example.com/project/admin/test?id=1**  would be the same as **www.example.com/project/admin/test.php?id=1**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php  -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-f
RewriteRule  (.*)  $1.php
```

Comment: its not removing .php extension and the query string ?id=..   @undone